# Expandafter issue

Tags: expansion

The problem is as follows: I need to pass the same set of options (say `angle=90, scale=0.85`) to a given command (say `\includepdf`) repeatedly. One approach is to save that option in some macro, say `\__Foo`. The problem is `\includepdf[\__Foo]` causes an error. I have proposed two ways to solve it, one with `\expandafter`, another with a custom function to be invoked with the command and the option. Neither of which satisfy me. Is there there a tool (in etoolbox?) to create a new function from `\includepdf`, say `\includepdfbis`, such that I can use it like this: `\includepdfbis[\__Foo]`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\__Foo{angle=90, scale=0.85}

\cs_new_protected:Nn\__erw_pass_option:Nn{#1[#2]}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__erw_pass_option:Nn {Ne}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%\includepdf[\__Foo]{example-image-a} % ERROR: Package keyval Error: angle=90,scale=0.85 undefined.

\expandafter\includepdf\expandafter[\__Foo]{example-image-a}

\__erw_pass_option:Ne \includepdf{\__Foo}{example-image-a}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternative to David's answer, you could even `\def\__Foo{\includepdf[angle=90, scale=0.85]}` and then invoke with `\__Foo{example-image-a}`, bypassing the need for expansion altogether.

Comment: This is what I settled for in the end. https://github.com/rogard/helpers.tex/blob/master/HelperBindOptions.tex

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, what's a good replacement for `xwatermark`?

Comment: I'm sorry, but `xwatermark` is not my forte, so I have no alternatives to offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is harmless to apply expandafter to the filename if no option is used, you can just unconditionally use the form you showed but wrapped in a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

% you would need expl3 package in older latex releases.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\__Foo{angle=90, scale=0.85}
% def not really the expl3 way but as you started..
\def\includepdfbis{\expandafter\includepdf\expandafter}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\includepdfbis[\__Foo]{example-image-a}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're better to define your own key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{Foo}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{angle=90, scale=0.85}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includepdf[Foo]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 'Gin' as in 'graphics instruction' (`graphicx`), and `\setkeys` is defined in `keyval`. Does this generalize to other keyval settings or just `graphicx`, and is there an `expl3` way to do it?

Comment: @Erwann If the package is based on keyval, one needs to use it. Look into it for finding the key namespace.