# Testing for \Foo vs \Foo*

Tags: expl3, starred-version

This is a follow up to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584161/expandafter-issue) whose problem statement (roughly): create a macro that saves a macro and options (`\includepdf[angle=90, scale=0.85]`), such as to be able to invoke it later (presumably repeatedly). Now I'd like to be able to do the same, but optionally with a star. (`\newwatermark*[page=\thepage,angle=45]`). For now, I'm trying to create a function that take as argument a macro and optionally a star, and that dispatches to different implementations whether that star is present or not. The code below compiles forever...

PS : preferably with package `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__erw_test:w #1 #2 \q_stop
{
  \token_if_eq_charcode:NNTF *#2{T}{F}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__erw_test:n
{
  \__erw_test:w #1 \q_stop \q_stop
}

\NewDocumentCommand\Foo{s}
{
  foo\IfBooleanT{#1}{star}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn


%\peek_charcode:NTF* { star } { no~star }
    

\__erw_test:n{\Foo}
%\__erw_test:n{\Foo*}


\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to have understood what you want...

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__erw_test:w #1 #2 \q_stop
  { \str_if_eq:nnTF { * } { #2 } { True } { False } }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__erw_test:n { \__erw_test:w #1 \q_stop }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

texte

\ExplSyntaxOn    
\__erw_test:n{\sqrt} ~   
\__erw_test:n{\sqrt*}    
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: One `\q_stop` too many in my example.