# How to map an expression such as \emph{\arabic*)} to \emph{\arabic{#1})}?

Tags: expl3, l3regex

Problem statement: take as input expressions suitable for the rhs of `label=` found in list options (`enumitem`), such as `\arabic*)` (item a) or `\emph{\arabic*)}` (item b), replace `*` with `{#1}`, and use that as the replacement expression of a function called `\g__erw_format:n`. For item a, I am able to solve this problem with a special `w`-function. Item b is a work in progress using regex. Hence my question: how to solve this problem for arbitrary expressions as specified?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcounter{foo}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \g__erw_format:n #1{}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \g__erw_star_a:w #1*#2 \q_stop{\cs_gset:Nn\g__erw_format:n{#1{##1}#2}}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \g__erw_star_a:n {\g__erw_star_a:w#1\q_stop}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \g__erw_star_b:n
{
  \cs_gset:Nn\g__erw_format:n{
    \tl_set:Nn\l_tmpa_tl{#1}
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { * } { {##1} } \l_tmpa_tl
%    \tl_to_str:N\l_tmpa_tl
    \token_to_meaning:N\l_tmpa_tl
%    \tl_use:N\l_tmpa_tl%%ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.
%%--- TeX said ---
%%<to be read again> 
%%                   \c@{ 
%%l.49 \g__erw_format:n{foo}    
  }
}

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584509/testing-for-foo-vs-foo

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\refstepcounter{foo}
\g__erw_star_a:n{\arabic*)}
\g__erw_format:n{foo}\\
%\g__erw_star_a:n{\emph{\arabic*)}} % ERROR File ended while scanning use of \g__erw_star_a:w
%\g__erw_format:n{foo}
\g__erw_star_b:n{\emph{\arabic*)}}
\g__erw_format:n{foo}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to save the argument in a token list with

```
\tl_set:Nn \l__erw_tmpa_tl {#1}
```

then do the regex replacement (note that you have to escape the `*` because it is a regex quantifier):

```
\regex_replace_once:nnN { \* } { \cB{\cP\#1\cE} } \l__erw_tmpa_tl
```

and only then insert the changed token list in the definition:

```
\exp_args:NNo \cs_gset:Nn \erw_format:n { \l__erw_tmpa_tl }
```

But note that this will replace *all* `*` by `{#1}`, so you may want to check that the `*` is preceded by `\arabic` or `\roman` or something like that.  You can do that rather easily by looping through a list of possible commands and trying to do the replacement:

```
\tl_const:Nn \c__erw_count_formats_tl
  { { arabic } { roman } { Roman } { alph } { Alph } }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \erw_star_b:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__erw_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \c__erw_count_formats_tl
      { \regex_replace_once:nnN { \c{##1}\* } { \c{##1}\cB{\cP\#1\cE} } \l__erw_tmpa_tl }
    \exp_args:NNo \cs_gset:Nn \erw_format:n { \l__erw_tmpa_tl }
  }
```

Also note that `\g__...`, `\l__...` and `\c__...` prefixes are for *variables*, not functions.  Functions have no prefix if they are public (for example `\erw_something:n`) or the `\__` prefix if they are private (for example `\__erw_something:n`).

Here's the MWE with both versions (I suggest you use version 2):

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcounter{foo}

\tl_new:N \l__erw_tmpa_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \erw_format:n #1 { }

% Version 1:
% \cs_new_protected:Nn \erw_star_b:n
%   {
%     \tl_set:Nn \l__erw_tmpa_tl {#1}
%     \regex_replace_once:nnN { \* } { \cB{\cP\#1\cE} } \l__erw_tmpa_tl
%     \exp_args:NNo \cs_gset:Nn \erw_format:n { \l__erw_tmpa_tl }
%   }

% Version 2:
\tl_const:Nn \c__erw_count_formats_tl
  { { arabic } { roman } { Roman } { alph } { Alph } }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \erw_star_b:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__erw_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \c__erw_count_formats_tl
      { \regex_replace_once:nnN { \c{##1}\* } { \c{##1}\cB{\cP\#1\cE} } \l__erw_tmpa_tl }
    \exp_args:NNo \cs_gset:Nn \erw_format:n { \l__erw_tmpa_tl }
  }

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584509/testing-for-foo-vs-foo

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\refstepcounter{foo}

\erw_star_b:n {\arabic*)}
\erw_format:n {foo}

\par

\erw_star_b:n {\emph{\arabic*)}}
\erw_format:n {foo}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: With the most recent updates to l3regex (not yet released on CTAN), `\cB{\cP\#1\cE}` can be replaced simply by `{\#1}`.  The backslash is still needed because converting `{#1}` to a string gives `{##1}`.